# How to work on the XAMPP & mongodb in windows?

Tags: php, web-applications, mongodb

Can any one let me know how to start working on the MongoDB in xampp(windows) with examples of applications?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Installing + testing the MongoDB sever: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows.
- Installing the win32 php module: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center#PHPLanguageCenter-Windows.
  Put the .dll into the xampp/php/ext directory (e.g. php_bz2.dll should already be in that directory).
  `<?php echo 'ini: ', ini_get('cfg_file_path')` tells you which php.ini you have to edit.
- Examples and documentation: http://docs.php.net/book.mongo.

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick reply. I will go through all the links!

Comment: Big-help!  Errors galore until I put that dll in the proper place and put its location in PHP.INI. Thanks for that one!

Comment: @VolkerK Can u able to sove this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910162/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-mongo-1-6-8-5-6-vc11-dll-in-php